# Javascript Script manager in a widget environment?

Tags: javascript, scriptmanager

I'm creating a website that could potentially contain many widgets. These widgets are rendered using external javascript code in external js files. Some of these widgets require the same external javascript files but i obviously dont want the browser including *(ie: )*  a javascript file whenever a widget requires one; instead it will only include a javascript file when it has not already been retrieved or is in the process of retrieving one.

Is there a javascript manager that can fulfill the requirements above? Extra points will be given to the solution with jQuery in mind :).

Answer (score 0):

I use Google's AJAX API to load jQuery and various other libraries I use.

It cuts down on bandwidth since the user won't get the resource from my server, and also the odds of them having the library are higher.

Here's a [link](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jquery).

Comment: I don't think he's talking about libraries, he's talking about his own custom code.  But I agree that unless he has a CDN of his own, he should be using Google's hosted libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo's `dojo.require` and `dojo.provide` does exactly what you are asking for.  Example:

```
dojo.require("com.project.widgets.someWidget");
```

Which would load `com/project/widgets/someWidget.js`.  Inside of that file, you would have

```
dojo.provide("com.project.widgets.someWidget");
```

Which registers the source as loaded.

It basically does a synchronous AJAX request, eval's the file, and marks the path as "fetched" so that it doesn't make the same request twice"